# How can I store a functions output into a variable in jq

Tags: jq, variable-assignment

I have been trying to convert months into days in my script. I managed to make a function that  turns an amount of months into days. I now want to store these days into a variable to be used in other functions later on.
I have tried:

```
days: .months|Months_to_Days
```

I have also tried to include it in an object with the month variable:

```
{
 months: "12",
 days: .months|Months_to_Days
}
```

This also doesn't work because when I did:

```
months: "12"
days: months
```

as a test, the days returned `null`. How can I do it?

I have tried:

```
days: .months|Months_to_Days
```

This returns:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 65:
 days: .months|Months_to_Days
```

The function Months_to_Days is:

```
eif .|tonumber > 8 then
     ((.|tonumber - 1) * 30) + ((.|tonumber - 1)/2) + 1 - 2|floor
    else
          if  .|tonumber < 3 then

       ((.|tonumber - 1) * 30) + (.|tonumber/2)| floor
    else
     ((.|tonumber - 1) * 30) + (.|tonumber/2) - 2| floor end| debug         
    end| debug
```

There is no input and it only uses the variables in the script.
The variables were:

```
{
 months: "12"
}
```

Before I wanted to make the variable storing the output of the function, I would run it with:

```
.months|Months_to_Days
```

There isn't an expected output just to store the output of the function to use in other functions.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The jq manual has a nice [section about variables](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Variable/SymbolicBindingOperator:...as$identifier|...). Why did that not work or was unclear? Where do you want to use your variables, what are your inputs, and what is your expected output? And it probably does not hurt to include the definition of your function too …

Comment: I removed the second half of your question, because this was just the first half of the question copy-pasted again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please show:

- Your input JSON
- Your function definition
- Your full jq program
- Your expected output JSON

Because I don't know what you are trying to do or what's not working. The following jq program works just fine:

```bash
$ printf '{"months": 5}' | jq 'def to_days: . * 30; # a very simple dummy impl
(.months|to_days) as $calculated_days # store in variable
| { days: $calculated_days }  # use variable'
```

Variables are explained in [Variable / Symbolic Binding Operator: ... as $identifier | ...](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Variable/SymbolicBindingOperator:...as$identifier%7C...) in the jq manual.

Comment: You might want to improve scalability by using parentheses as in `(.months|to_days) as $calculated_days`, just in case the original input needs to be reused as in e.g. `. + { days: $calculated_days }` (without parentheses before `as`, `.months` would be propagated instead).

Comment: @pmf thanks, this always trips me up in my own scripts too. TBH, I find the precedence of `|`, `,`, and `as` a bit counter-intuitive at times.

Comment: I have looked at the jq manual multiple times and what I understood is that variables can only be in objects or arrays? This is what confused me a little. I am new to this language and I also know some C#. It appears to be very different.

Comment: @IoannisApostolopoulos yes, jq is a very unique language :) and no, variables can hold any value. they don't exist "in" something, they are available in their current scope (their parenthized expression)